# How can I define variables in a JavaScript file within an html file in which the JavaScript is used?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have searched for an answer, but I haven't found a answer that address my issue, as I'm not how to word it as a search. My problem is that I want to use the same JS code for multiple HTML files, but only a few values need to be changed in the JS depending on the HTML file.

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Replace:: Line 14, Line 82: 'PROJECT' with name of the project; Line 15: '0' with the last counted image; line 94: 'PROJECT' with base name of picture files-->
<!--fill in any special instructions at each step in the text array.-->
<html>
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../defaultStyle.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src = "../buttons.js">

var num = 0
var NAME = PROJECT
var LAST = 100
var LAST1 = LAST-1

text[0] = "a"
text[1] = "b"
<!--...etc-->

</script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../projectStyle.css"/>

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <p href="JavaScript:StepDisplay()" id="Step">PROJECT</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Text">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="button" onClick="JavaScript:Back()"> Back</button>
        <button type="button" onClick="JavaScript:Next()"> Next</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="image/PROJECT (0).jpg" id="Pic">
    </div>

</body>
</html>


***JavaScript***

var text = new Array[100]
var num = 0
var NAME = PROJECT
var LAST = 100
var LAST1 = 99

function Next(){
    num = num + 1
    if (num == LAST)
    {num = 0}
    stepnum = num.toString();
    document.getElementById("Pic").src = "image/"+ NAME + "(" + stepnum + ").jpg"
    document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = text[num]
    if (num == 0)
    document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = NAME
    if (num == 1)
    document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = "Pieces"
    if (num > 1)
    document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = "Step " + (num-1).toString();
}

function Back(){
    num = num - 1
    if (num < 0)
    {num = LAST1}
    stepnum = num.toString();
    document.getElementById("Pic").src = "image/" + NAME +  "(" + stepnum + ").jpg"
    document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = text[num]
    if (num == 0)
    document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = NAME
    if (num == 1)
    document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = "Pieces"
    if (num > 1)
    document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = "Step " + (num-1).toString();
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What part needs to change depending on the HTML file? The general answer is that you should define functions or classes, and the things that change should be provided as arguments to the functions.

Comment: wrap your `buttons` script into an obj or function, then pass `num`, `NAME`, ... in as arguments

Comment: @Fabricator, beaurriful :-)

Comment: The HTML file here is In each HTML file, where it says "PROJECT", I will manually change each instance to the project name relevant to a folder of images for that project, each picture named 'project (number).jpg'. I need to use that name in the JS code to display the images and any text relevant to each picture. All this text is held in an array, and each time a button is clicked, it ttraverses the array displaying the proper text for the image. I have had this work when I had the JS code in the HTML file, but I just want to reference one JS file for each HTML file.

Comment: @user1888736 - Sorry, that comment was for another question.  I was trying to figure out which question I commented on by mistake, but you beat me to it.  I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your local variables before including the script.

```
<script>
    // local variables
    var firstname = "John", lastname = "Doe";
</script>
<script src="hellohello.js"></script>
```

In the js file, we need to make sure our local variables exists, if it doesn't we can define default variables or stop the script.

```
// Check if the variable already exists

// If it doesn't we'll give it a default variable
if(typeof(firstname)==='undefined') firstname = "Guest";
if(typeof(lastname)==='undefined') lastname = "";
alert("Hello "+ firstname +" "+ lastname);

// Or just do something else
if(typeof(firstname)!=='undefined' && typeof(lastname)!=='undefined') {
   // Do something
} else {
   // Do nothing
}
```

Demo 1: http://bycreativeminds.com/playground/vanilla/js-demo-110.html
Demo 2: http://bycreativeminds.com/playground/vanilla/js-demo-111.html

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to include the script first and then override the variables inline?  I thought that it paused running JavaScript until all scripts were loaded?  Do you have to change the variables in onLoad (or $(document).ready) instead?

Comment: Defining a variable before loading the script is much simpler.

Comment: Ah.  I see what you are up to.  Ok, I'm going to post a different way, but I don't necessarily think it is any better.

Comment: Would I need to initialize the variables in the JS file or only in the HTML file?

Comment: @user1888736 Only in the HTML document, however you can add a default value or a default behavior if the variable is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is better then hutchbat's or not, but it is a different way.

What I did was break up buttons.js into two files: buttons_init.js and buttons.js

buttons_init.js includes all the intialization, but not the code that uses it

```
var text = new Array[100]
var num = 0
var NAME = PROJECT
var LAST = 100
var LAST1 = 99
```

So in your HTML, you do this (preferably at the buttom unless you need it to run early):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "../buttons_init.js">
<script>
    // overwrite any variables you need to change
    num = 5
    LAST = 200
    LAST1 = LAST-1
</script>
<script src = "../buttons.js>
```

The advantage of this is that you don't have to remember to check to see a variable is undefined in your buttons_init.js.  The disadvantage is that you have two files to include (which slows down the load slightly, although not as much as it used to) and you have to remember to put default variables you want people to override in the _init file (which has the side affect of documenting it).  Some people will prefer one way, some will prefer the other.  I'm just presenting it as an alternative.

A completely different way would be to send an "options" structure into the Next and Prev functions (merging them with default values inside the functions), or make them into a class (or jQuery plugin), but that seems overkill for such a simple example.

Comment: So I did this and I still am not getting it to work. I can't post the content here, I don't have enough characters. I really don't want to have another file for each project I have for this, so I just put all the variables in a script in the HTML document, as @hutchbat suggested. This should work the same, right?

Comment: Yes, it should work the same.  If you like hutchbat's answer, by all means, go with it.  I was just trying to provide other alternatives that I feel were equal.