# How can I define variables within an HTML file, which are used in an external JS file, when importing the JS code into my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

The problem: I can get this to work if I include the JS code in each HTML file and manually insert all the variables. When I have the following it won't work.

The code:

--HTML code--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    name = "PROJECT"<!--Change 'PROJECT' to the name of the project-->
    num = 0 <!--Keep 0-->
    last = 60 <!--Change to the number of pictures in the project folder, minus the thumbnail-->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    text = new Array(last)
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../buttons.js"></script>

...

<div>
        <button type="button" onClick="JavaScript:Back()"> Back</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="JavaScript:Next()"> Next</button>
</div>
```

----JavaScript code---

```
function FillArray(){ //Fill the array with empty strings
    for(i = 0; i < last; i++){
         text[i] = " "
    }
}

FillArray();

function Next(){
    num = num + 1
    if (num == last)
        {num = 0}
    stepnum = num.toString();
    document.getElementById("Pic").src = "image/" + name + (" + stepnum + ").jpg"
    document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = text[num]
    if (num == 0)
        document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = name
    if (num == 1)
        document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = "Pieces"
    if (num > 1)
        document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = "Step " + (num-1).toString();
}

function Back(){
    num = num-1
    if (num < 0)
        {num = last-1}
    stepnum = num.toString();
    document.getElementById("Pic").src = "image/" + name + (" + stepnum + ").jpg"
    document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = text[num]
    if (num == 0)
        document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = name
    if (num == 1)
        document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = "Pieces"
    if (num > 1)
        document.getElementById("Step").innerHTML = "Step " + (num-1).toString();
}
```

Comment: You can't use HTML comment inside `<script>` it's expecting JS comments, this would make fail already. You need to learn to use `var` as in a variable declaration `var i = 0;` otherwise all your variable end up on the global scopes. `FillArray` use a variable text which doesn't seem to be define. Always end your line of JS with `;`, it's cleaner and safer.

Comment: You have A LOT of syntax errors in your script.  Also, try to avoid reserved words like "name" and "title" etc...

Comment: I should have mentioned that the HTML code is seperate from the JS, and that the JS code is "buttons.js", which is called in the HTML code. I have had the code work, as is, when placed directly into the HTML documents and filling in the appropriate values instead of having variables. I want to use a separate JS file though, as I have 20 different HTML documents using the same code. I thought that var was unnecessary as the variables are global

Comment: @user1888736 If you want your variables to be global, better declare them in global context, or use them as properties of `window`. Omitting `var` is not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: take care with duplicating your own questions, that most likely will not make you and new friends. Instead edit [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195573/how-can-i-define-variables-in-a-javascript-file-within-an-html-file-in-which-the) to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a few errors. First, you should have semicolons after your Javascript lines

```
    name = "PROJECT";
    num = 5;
    last = 60;
    text = new Array(last);
```

Also, you are missing quotation marks on two lines (This is your real error I think). They should be:

```
    document.getElementById("Pic").src = "image/" + name + "(" + stepnum + ").jpg"
```

Finally, you should probably wait until all your external js files load before calling FillArray() but I don't really think that is your issue either.

```
    window.onload = function() {
      FillArray();
    };
```

Comment: That did it! Odd that prior to semicolons it was working anyway. Originally I thought I had to have them, but then it was working without them, so I thought it didn't matter. Also thanks for paying attention for me on those quotation marks!